# Set Candy Icon Theme for every icon in KDE Plasma

Tags: kde, icons

I really like the Candy Icon Theme and original icon is usually replaced by the theme. (Dolphin, VSCode, Discord etc). But doesn't work for Chromium and IntelliJ even if it has icons for it.
For changing application volume, the Candy Icon of Chromium is displayed in the menu; but on the Latte Dock, the logo stays the same.

Comment: Some apps use GTK2 and GTK3.  Have you set the icon theme under `Appearance > Application Style > GNOME Application Style (GTK)`?

Comment: both gtk2 and 3 are set to breeze. What am I supposed to do now?

Comment: set the icon theme of your choice.  If an app doesn't use gtk or qt, it won't respond to themes.